# htacces redirect to subdir

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i want to redirect my url to a sub dir, without changing the url (visible)

i want everything that has the `/assets/.....` in the url go to `/resources/theme/assets`
everything else should go to `/public/index.php`

i tried this code, but that was not working

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^assets/?$ /resources/flatkit/assets/ [L,NC]
```

but that is not working

can someone help me with this .htaccess problem.

Comment: What exacly isnt working? and where is your htaccess located?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow for part after `assets/` in your pattern and use it in target using a back-reference:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^assets(/.*)?$ /resources/flatkit/$0 [L,NC]

# rule for public/index.php
```